# extend debug(character) with debug(longchar) openedge

Tags: openedge

I need to log messages that will possibly exceed the 32k character limit. How can I extend the LogWriter with a debug(character) or what would be the best way to use the Logging Framework to log messages that are greater than 32k characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but it takes a bit of code.

The first step is to use the `debug(LogMessage, ...)` method, rather than `debug(character, ...)` method.

You will need to build the `LogMessage` but can't use its public properties (since they are also `character`. So you will need to use the `LogMessage`'s `AddContext` method. This takes a character for the key and a `Progress.Lang.Object` as the value. You can use an instance of `OpenEdge.Core.String`, which holds longchar values.

```
using OpenEdge.Logging.*.
using OpenEdge.Core.*.

define variable logger as ILogWriter no-undo.
define variable logMsg as LogMessage no-undo.

logger = LoggerBuilder:GetLogger('something').

// do stuff

define variable longcharWithLotsOfData as longchar no-undo.

logMsg = new LogMessage(logger:Name, 'short message').
logMsg:AddContext('long-message', new String(longcharWithLotsOfData)).

logger:debug(logMsg).
```

You will probably also need to add your own filter to read this message from that context, and write it into the logfile. You can see an example of how to create one [here](https://github.com/PeterJudge-PSC/abl-logging-demo) .

You'll need to write to a 'named file' rather than the `LOG-MANAGER` since the `WRITE-MESSAGE()` method only takes a character for the message.

The writer will need to output the String object's `Value` property;  `ToString()` returns a character. The filter will need to check the type of the object returned from the `GetContext()` method, and cast it to get the value.

You will need to use the `COPY-LOB... APPEND` statement to write the longchar value to the output file.

There are basically 3 steps

1. Create a class that implements `ILoggerFilter`
2. Add the filter definition to the `filter` property in `logging.config`
3. Add the filter to your logger(s) in `logging.config`

Comment: I was wondering about log message object. I will give it a spin tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks, it worked although the log file showed just part of the full string with a   <<...MORE...>> at the end. Is there a way to force a full output of the string?